# Resizing a UITextView with a maximum height

Tags: iphone, uitextview, max

I am displaying some text from a sqlite3 database and would like the UITextView to resize automatically depending on the amount of text.  I can do this fine as follows:

```
TextLabel.scrollEnabled = YES;
TextLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[TextLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(55.10, 26.15, TextLabel.contentSize.width, 
                                             TextLabel.contentSize.height)];
```

This works fine.  I am struggling when trying to set a maximum height.

So the UITextView will resize to the text unless it reaches a maxiumum height in which case the user will have to use the scroll bar to view the remaining text.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to discover the desired height for some multiline text:

```
int myWidth = 300;
int maxHeight = 9999;
NSString *myString = @"lorem ipsum dolor yadda";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(myWidth, maxHeight)
                               lineBreakMode:textLabel.lineBreakMode];

textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, myWidth, myStringSize.height);
```

I got this from nevan's answer to this previous question:

- [UILabel: vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/uilabel-vertical-alignment)

Reference: [Apple's docs on NSString UIKit additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).