# Label Text alignment with multiple lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, label, alignment

I have a label with multiple lines .I want the text on the label always starts from top left corner independent of the height and number of lines of label.

Right now i am using a property

```
[question1Label setContentMode: UIViewContentModeTopLeft];
```

But its not working

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've noticed that *contentMode* property of *UILabel* doesn't affect its text's alignment.  Use the *textAlignment* property.

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

**Edit:** This will align the text Center-Left. In order to show the text from Top-Left you need to find the height of the text using `sizeWithFont:` method of *NSString*. [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/uilabel-vertical-alignment) to know how to do it.

As an alternative you can use `UITextField`, the subclass of `UIControl`, which inherits *UIControl's* the `contentVerticalAlignment` property.

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

You can use this property to align the text on top. You can disable the user from editing the text by using the property `userInteractionEnabled` property.

Comment: i use this property but it only align the text from left but i want to start my text from the top.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer no longer worked for me as UITextAlignmentLeft has been depreciated.

The following works great!

```
// Allow multiline label centered
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```