# Is it possible to vertically align text inside labels with a "large" frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

In my application I have multiple tableviews with custom cells. Some of the text in the cells are spread out on between 2-4 lines so the height of the label is large enough to contain the content.

However on iPad the screen is larger and I want the text to appear at the top left point of the label, not in the middle as it do when you use `numberOfLines` property. I know you can horizontally align the text, but it must be possible to align the text to the top left also? Or is it impossible.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Check this page
[Vertically align text within a UILabel][1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Its *impossible* to align the text in *UILabel* vertically. But, you can dynamically change the height of the label using **sizeWithFont:** method of *NSString*, and just set its *x* and *y* as you want.

As an alternative you can use **UITextField**. It supports the **contentVerticalAlignment** peoperty as it is a subclass of **UIControl**. You have to set its **userInteractionEnabled** to *NO* to prevent user from typing text on it.

Comment: thank you, would uitextfield lead to poorer performance or other things in tableviewcell or is it just as good?

Comment: @Andreas, Yes. Its fine to use UITextField inside table view cells. In my personal opinion,  using UILabels and dynamically sizing it would be the correct way. Anyway, its upto you to choose. Both way are fine. ;-)

Comment: With UITextField you got that ugly frame around the text no?

Comment: @Sharen Eayrs, You can prevent that by setting textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone.

Answer (score 3):

I actually noticed that using

```
[Blue setSizeToFit]
```

does align vertically to the top. The default being centered.

Comment: The way it really work is that it is still aligned centered but now the top remain the same and the box is just "right" so it looks like it's aligned top. This serves most people's purpose. However, you can set background to a certain color and verify things your end.

Comment: make sure your constraints are set correct, so that the label is allowed to shrink or grow

Answer (score 3):

`sizeToFit` does not work in `UITableCellView`, because the Cells are reused during scrolling.

The solution is to calculate the table cell height according to the font and font size and adjust the label height to it.

As it was quite difficult to find the solution on the web I wrote a [short post](http://hons82.blogspot.com/2012/09/uilabel-change-vertical-alignment.html) about it

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows

1. Set your label's `numberOfLines` property 0 from IB
2. Set your label's `lineBreakMode` as `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` (**very very important**)

now whatever you set on the label just append few @"\n" to it.....
ex.-

```
[yourTextLabel setText:@"myLabel\n\n\n\n\n"];
```

Comment: If you do this, the text will always have ellipsis, won't it?

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 7 `sizeWithFont:` is now deprecated! 
Several solutions like subclassing `UILabel` have to be adapted.

My solution for top aligned label text:
In a subclass `TopVerticalAlignmentLabel : UILabel` override `drawRect:` as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect labelStringRect = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                     options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                  attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: self.font, /* further attributes */}
                                                     context:nil];

    [super drawTextInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, labelStringRect.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

make sure your constraints are set correct, so that the label is allowed to shrink or grow. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Same Question asked by SomeOne. you'll find more appropriate way to solve this problem.they guys did great explanation over it.

I think so, you should take a look of  this.

here in that thread many answers suggest set the dynamic frame for the UILabel on the basis of  `text` as below snippet of code described.

```
    CGSize theStringSize = [textToBeUsed sizeWithFont:lblTitle.font  constrainedToSize:labelSize lineBreakMode:lblTitle.lineBreakMode];
    lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(lblTitle.frame.origin.x, lblTitle.frame.origin.y, theStringSize.width, theStringSize.height);
    lblTitle.text = theText;

   // lblTitle is the Label used for showing the Text.
```

you can get more precise idea rather than using `textField` [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel/13287659#13287659)

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply Use A UITextView ,and Set its UserInteraction Enabled to No,And All of your problems will be solved!