# Custom UITableViewCell with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

My goal is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains 2 UILabels. One is the title and one is the detail. The detail label should allow for 3 rows of text.

So I went on and created a custom table view cell in storyboard. I also created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and linked the two together.

I the added two `UILabel` to the cell in storyboard and placed them where i wanted them to be and linked them to their coresponding outlets in teh subclass. Since the content of the labels varies I wanted to align the text vertically to the top. As I understand the only way to do this is by calling the `sizeToFit` method on the label. I execute this under in the sub class of `UITableViewCell`:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     [self.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

So far everything seems fine and the text in the `detailTextLabel` is aligned as it should. Although when i satrt interacting with the cell, for example slide my finger over it so the delete button appears, the `detailTextLabel` will change size to the size that was set in storyboard. This causes the text to be misaligned. Similar things happen when i select the cell and change to another view and the return to the table view via a tab bar

My question is: Is there any way of creating this custom cell differently using storyboard or is my only alterative to create everything programtically?

Regard, Christian

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557178/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-inside-labels-with-a-large-frame) if you still want to vertically align your text in your UILabel without `sizeToFit` (who will resize it when you will interact with your cell).

About your question, I think you can create your custom cell from a xib file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939305/1437192).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, one alternative would be to use xib file. However I was trying to stick storyboard. I was able to solve the above problem by using a standard UITableViewCell with the "subtitle" style. Then i changed the detailTextLabel.numberOfRows to equal 0. I then called the sizeToFit on detailTextLabel. All this under layoutSubviews.