# Make UILabel's text "Stick" to the top when having multiple lines - ios

Tags: ios, uilabel, lines

I have a UILabel which is loaded using a xib files, with the maximum of 2 rows.
When I have 2 rows of text, it all works fine, but If I have only 1, it is being written in the middle of the label, and I dont want that to happen. I just want it to stick to the top, as if the label was high enough for 1 row.

How can I implement this?
Tnx!

Comment: Here is the same question with a great answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/uilabel-vertical-alignment

Comment: thank you for that :) haven't shown up when I looked for it, probably becuase of the "vertical" term.

Comment: You can get your Answer from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel

- Mits Bhadeshiya