# Label not hugging text properly

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I'm struggling with a problem. Some labels are not being calculated correctly in my list.

As you can see in the image below, when the text is too large an ellipsis is added to the end of the label and there is an extra space on the top and bottom of the label. But when the text has only 3 lines, the label size hugs the text properly.

[image: Link to the image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show how you configured constraints (or frame, if you're using it) for label.

Comment: Yeah, of corse. Here are the images [Image 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34017421/Captura%20de%20Tela%202016-11-06%20%C3%A0s%2005.34.45.png) [Image 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34017421/Captura%20de%20Tela%202016-11-06%20%C3%A0s%2005.34.57.png) [Image 3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34017421/Captura%20de%20Tela%202016-11-06%20%C3%A0s%2005.35.17.png)

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko maybe is a bug from Apple?

Comment: one moment, i will check it myself

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605341/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel-note-using-autolayout

Comment: Actually I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34129989/3550013) approach

Comment: And I tried that solution but didn't work :/ The text was not drawn correctly.