# how can I align the text of my label in swift so that it starts in the top left corner of the label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a textfield with `lines` property set to 0, so that when the text is longer it will automatically fill all the necessary space. But when the string is short, it is automatically placed in the middle of the label, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way (or maybe a property to set) of putting this text in the top left corner? This is my attribute inspector for that label:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Autolayout you can try to set only `top`, `left` and `right` constraints without any height constraint. That should work, but if you are not using Autolayout or you are having trouble changing these constraints you can also call `label.sizeToFit()` after setting the text.

To call `sizeToFit`, if you are setting the text on `viewDidLoad` or in the Storyboard itself, you can call it on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    label.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a default option in Xcode, you could use the work around in the other answer or alternatively just use a TextView which by default gives you the top left behaviour you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

you would think this would be easy, but it appears to not be.  There's a good solution outlined here [how to set top left alignment for UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192088/how-to-set-top-left-alignment-for-uilabel-for-ios-application)