# text inside UILabel is placed vertically in the middle instead of from the top - how can I change it in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel, drawtext

In my `swift` app I added a `UILabel` that is positioned below the mapkit - both elements are in my static `UITableViewCell`. My point in it was that with longer text, the `UILabel` would expand in size.

In `storyboard` it looks like this:

[image]

and the constraints for the label look as follows:

[image]

This `UILabel` has assigned class `ActiveLabel` taken from here: https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift

Currently when there's a lot of text it looks like this:

[image]

and that's fine, but when there's a short text, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way of moving the single line to the top of the label, so that the text starts right below the map?

I think the problem might be somewhere in the [ActiveLabel class](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift/blob/master/ActiveLabel/ActiveLabel.swift) , maybe in the `drawText` method, but I'm not sure, could you help me with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set top-left alignment for UILabel for iOS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192088/how-to-set-top-left-alignment-for-uilabel-for-ios-application)

Comment: Put your label to the top-left and make a dynamic height with the size of your text.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to align the text to the top on a UILabel if it has large height. You should rethink your constraints and make the height of the label the same as the text. Make the bottom space to superview >= const and remove the height constraint.