# Need proper Text Alignemnt in UILabel of Dynamic Height iphone

Tags: iphone, dynamic, height, uilabel

I have UILabel with dynamic height. But when my label has less characters then content of uilabel is aligned correctly. But if characters are more the content alignment changes. Please see following screenshots

[image]

[image]

As shown in above images text alignment is shifted down words.
Here is my code

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *lognString = @"HAAAasfkjfg;jpgijopfadsgdfk;glsdfkls;gja;sjgasd;kjfgasod;fjals;dkfj kl;asddfjs;aipsdfj;asdjfs";

    CGRect frame = label.frame;

    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;

    frame.size.height = [self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lognString font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f] width:210.0 mode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    label.frame = frame;

    label.text = lognString;
}

-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*)text   font:(UIFont*)withFont  width:(float)width mode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{

    CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

    return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

Kindly ignore the text in UILable as this is a sample application
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel