# Use the second line of uiLabel if uilabel only have one line

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uilabel

In iOS project, I am creating an UILabel with 2 lines of text capacity, and i specified that the UILabel can content 2 lines. If the text only is 1 line, how can specify that the text is writing in the second line and the first be empty?

In other words, i would like that the text was writing in the UILabel from bottom to top.

Specifications:

The UILabel must be 2 lines maxium bigger.

**If the text only needs 1 line of UILabel, the line which should be write is the second**

If the text needs 2 lines, the UILabel should be completed first with the first line and then the second line.(normally. it works)

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align text within a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

Comment: Even if this is not a duplicate I strongly suggest that you at least read the question linked by @JonGrant, it's very informative and should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: numberOfLines = 0 lets you create any number of lines based on text content.