# Want to change position of label to top-left programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created a label , and now i want to change its postion of display on screen so how can i do that programmatically?

My screen look like this when i first start it.

[image: this is how it is display now]

But i want to display it like this when it will first time open.

[image: i want to display it like this]

Comment: Check this link, may be this help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you creating label programmatically ,so than you have to set code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    yourlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    yourlabel.text = @"text";

    yourlabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:alabel];
}
```

this should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from view. Then change the frame of the UIlabel . Then add it to view.

```
[yourLabel removeFromSuperView];
temp.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);  //set the frame as you want
[self.view addSubView:yourLabel];
```

Comment: Your example will perfectly work but there is no need to use a temp variable :) Just removing from superview, changing the frame and adding it again would equally work.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify label's `frame` property. It's of type `CGRect`:

```
struct CGRect {
   CGPoint origin;
   CGSize size;
};
```

To change it's position, change the `origin` point values. It corresponds to the label's top left point.

```
CGRect labelFrame = [label frame];
labelFrame.origin.x = 50; // set to whatever you want
labelFrame.origin.y = 100;
[label setFrame:labelFrame];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //simply you change origin for label
 //it make animation for moving label in the view
    -(void)your_action
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                              delay:1.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             label.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//this code used for drag label in view,to click in view label origin change to touch point

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
        point = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             label.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y,width, height);
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }

//enable user interaction for label
```