# UILabel auto resize and add scroll bar if necessary?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I've looked around for an answer here but didn't come along one that really helped me. directing me to a proper answer I may have missed is greatly appreciated too.

I have a label defined in the simplest manner :

```
    IBOutlet UILabel *eventIDLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *eventTitleLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *eventDescriptionLabel;
```

now the description label can vary in content. May have 1 line or multiple lines. I want the label to resize automatically. Now I also want that if more lines than current screen can show, user is enable to scroll down and see the whole content of label.

Very trivial question probably but I am really new and hoping you guys could help.

thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UITextView. UITextView automatically can be scrolled, when the entered text ist to long.

Comment: excellent looks like what I really needed. What about justifying it? It is aligned to the left. I can understand if you do not wish to answer 2nd question here

Comment: To justify set textAlignment property of UITextView. But for this kind of questions, you really should just check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[myLabel sizeToFit]`

You can also read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

Also if you know it's going to be relatively long, you can consider using TextView which will provide the text scrolling

Hope I helped