# Can't get both Numberoflines and textAlignment to work

Tags: xcode, uilabel

When I first created the UIButton, the NSTextAlignment was always correct.

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,landscapes?450:380, 120)];
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,landscapes?450:380, 120);
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:60];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
label.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = true;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSLog(@"%i",label.textAlignment);
label.text = n;
[self addSubview:label];
```

However, every time I put in a parameter for the number of lines

```
label.numberOfLines = 2;
```

The label is not text aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this other stackoverflow post about vertical alignment. I think using sizeToFit with numberOfLines=0 and then specifying the width will help you get it horizontally centered too - [Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel) .