# is there any way to make TextFlied input like google wallet input in ios ? please see attached photo for your understanding what i need

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I want same textfield or any control in iOS Objective-C, like this image 
 google wallet input entry.

Comment: possible but did you search on Google or simple on other open hub. As beginner explain your question as much possible & avoid negative marking.

Comment: thanks for responds, can you please give me any reference link? becuase i have done lots of search and i can't found same like my need.

Comment: look few examples I have never run them but should work 1 https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField   2 https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField  3 https://github.com/TheMrugraj/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField   Also there is an openhub name cocoacontrol.com  go on this site & search for ur ui

Comment: Hey @Gagan, thanks but i already checked all link provided by you, and also i have checked on cocoa control, ioslibs and all hub, and i can't found solution from any where, thats why i am put my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes totally possible Use NSAttributed String here is the link [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Create 2 NSDictionary one for smaller fontSize and one for Bigger fontSize.
in the small font size Attributed Dictionary the size for the **NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName** is used to move the small font up or down change the value to see the effect.

```
// I have added the attribute for font color as well so it should look the same as picture above
NSDictionary *smallFontSize = @{
                                NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10],
                                NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor]
                                };
```

Second dictionary is very simple it only contains the font Size

```
NSDictionary *bigFontSize = @{
                              NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]
                              };
```

Declare **NSMutableAttributedString** not **AttributedString** pass in the samllFontSize

```
// I have directly passed the $ sign but you will pass it as a property
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttriString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"$" attributes:smallFontSize];
```

Now create two new **AttributedStrings** these 2 can be attributedString because we are not manipulating them

```
// You will be passing the amount and decimals as properties
NSAttributedString *amount = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"10" attributes:bigFontSize];
NSAttributedString *decimalAmount = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"00" attributes:smallFontSize];
```

Now try to append both amount and decimalAmount to the **mutableAttributedString** that was the reason we made the first one mutable so we can append to it later

```
[mutableAttriString appendAttributedString:amount];
[mutableAttriString appendAttributedString:decimalAmount];
```

Each label has a property called **text** and another one called **attributedText** add it to the attributedText property

```
self.priceLabel.attributedText = mutableAttriString
```

Here is the screenshot of the label change the font and colours to your liking.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hello @khalid thanks for responds, i know it possible, can you please give me example of code.

Comment: please see this example [Top-aligning text of different sizes within a UILabel
] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537033/top-aligning-text-of-different-sizes-within-a-uilabel)

Comment: Done added a quick example hope it's what he want's

Comment: Hello @Khalid afridi, Thanks for your Support, yes your provided link is worked for me, because i need this thing when user types on textfield then i have call (shouldChangeCharactersInRange method of textfield) i need to just do minor changes. but thanks for you support. it is very useful code.

Comment: @KhalidAfridi for display this amount on label, your provided code is work like charm. thank you very much.