# iOS - let UILabel stretch to downside when there are multiple lines

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am using `setNumberOfLines` and `sizeToFit` to resize my label in tableView cells dynamically. When there are more than 2 lines, my label will stretch to upside, but I want to make it stretch down.

let's say I have `label1` and  `label2`. their `y` position is the same before setting `label.text`:

```
label1         label2
---------     --------- 
|       |     |       |
---------     ---------
```

label1 has only one line while label2 has two lines after setting `label.text` separately. it looks like this now:

```
label1         label2
              --------- 
---------     | line1 |
| line1 |     | line2 |
---------     ---------
```

however, what I want is:

```
label1         label2                  
---------     ---------
| line1 |     | line1 |
---------     | line2 |
              ---------
```

I believe there is a simple way to achieve my goal, but I can't find it by googling with the keyword I can think up.

my code:

```
myLabel.text = value;
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: I've updated it. I think it doesn't matter though. it's just as simple as every sample code of resizing `UILabel` dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a label in a table view cell from stretching up, you have to make a `Top Space to` constraint for the label on storyboard:

[image]

you can make it by dragging your label to near the top of the cell, and Xcode would generate it automatically. you can modify the value of the constraint by clicking the button on the right-bottom of this picture.

After making the constraint, the label won't stretch up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *text1 = @"Your text for label2";
CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(125, 2000);   //width of your label....
CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  //font of your label

cell.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,125,size1.height); 
//posy is same as for label1
cell.myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.myLabel.text = text1;
```

Comment: this sounds logical, but it doesn't work. my label is in tableView cell, does it matter?

Comment: so, you can easily set frame of label of your custom cell... see my edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to specifically set the frame according to the text so that the label to show so

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(Width,VeryLargeHeight);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [string sizeWithFont:label.font                        
                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                  lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

expectedLabelSize.height is the height of label to set in frame and set numberofLines to 0

Comment: this sounds logical, but it doesn't work. my label is in tableView cell, does it matter?

Comment: yes ofcourse it matters you have to adjust the height of tableview to view it properly

Answer (score 0):

`sizeToFit` will move the text content to the top of the frame. Refer diagram in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054681/1407017).
Instead make use of `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` API to get exact height of the text and then set this to your label.

Answer (score 0):

Every answer posted before can be used for your problem with some additions. It's important that your text is into a UITableViewCell (custom or not). If your value returned by `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is greater than the label height then the code will work, if not, the label will be wrongly displayed.

So you have to return the correct value from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in order to display the content as you need, so please compute the needed height of the text that you want to display in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` (+- other values if you have other views). 
Also if you are using autloayout check the constraints on your cell views, if not check the spring and struts on your cell views.