# When setting the frame of a UILabel, is it possible to set it to the vertical and horizontal center of the superview in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

Like, `CGRectMake()`, but have it specify the center, both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: You want the frame to be the same size as the superview, then center it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the dimensions of the containing view.
2. Get the dimensions of the view to be inserted.
3. x_position = width_of_containing_view / 2.0 - width_of_inserted_view / 2.0
4. y_position = height_of_containing_view / 2.0 - height_of_inserted_view / 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `label.center = [superview convertPoint:superview.center fromView:superview.superview];` =P

Answer (score 0):

Set the label's `center` property to the center point of it's superview's `bounds`. Since the superview's `center` and `frame` properties are in coordinate space of *their* superview, those properties aren't helpful (unless you do the conversion like fumoboy does).

`label.center = CGRectGetMidPoint(label.superview.bounds);`

I made this function for convenience:

```
CGPoint CGRectGetMidPoint(CGRect rect)
{
    return CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
}
```