# In UILabel how to multiline text with custom width

Tags: objective-c, ios6

My `UILabel` is in `UITableViewCell` and Here is my code

```
lblgoal = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,10, 250, 20)];
CGSize maximumLabelSize1 = CGSizeMake(230,9999);
            lblgoal.numberOfLines = 0;
            lblgoal.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
            CGSize expectedLabelSize = [sg.subgoal_name sizeWithFont:lblgoal.font
                                                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                   lineBreakMode:lblsubgoal1.lineBreakMode];
CGRect newFrame = lblgoal.frame;
            newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
            lblgoal.frame = newFrame;
```

But this only works if i put the width of `UILabel` to 200, if i put more than 200 width, then it all comes in one line with dotted at the end. And, `UITableView` cell width is more than 500.

Comment: use `[alabel setNumberOFlines:5];` and look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1054681/2239920)

Comment: how big is your cell height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, make sure to set the `linebreakmode` to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` in both your sizeWithFont function and your lblgoal label as below:

```
lblgoal.numberOfLines = 0;
lblgoal.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; //NSLineBreakByWordWrapping for iOS 6
```

EDIT: Try `sizeToFit` after you set the `lineBreakMode`.

```
[lblgoal sizeToFit];
```

Also make sure you do this inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

You should also implement the following delegate method to make sure the height of your cell is also adjusted accordingly.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: by the way in ios 6 its, NSLineBreakByWordWrapping, but this doesn't work either, thanks

Comment: you are correct about NSLineBreakByWordWrapping if your target is iOS 6. try sizeToFit. That is the simplest solution for UITableViewCell aside from subclassing UITableViewCell

Comment: when i use sizetofit, the whole text inside label disappear

Comment: hey i think adding lblgoal.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; after numberoflines work, thanks a lot for saving my time

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed Width when you are checking for the MaximumLabelSize.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize1 = CGSizeMake(230,9999);
```

Instead Use

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize1 = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
```

But this will give the Oppurtunity to extend width to any extend. Which is not going to 
work for u.. So set the Maximum Width to 500.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize1 = CGSizeMake(500, MAXFLOAT);
```

And set the Frame for the Label :

```
CGRect newFrame = lblgoal.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     if (!self.lastIndexPath) 
     {
        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
     }

    if ([self.lastIndexPath row] != [indexPath row])
    {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;  
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
```