# Two line UILabel with word wrap and truncate also aligned at vertically top

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel

I have to take 2 line label. On the first line i need line break mode NSLineBreakByWordWrapping and on second line NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle. Also if text fits in single line it should be vertically top aligned.

I am using iOS6 and autolayout. I can align single line text to top but the problem is that if text length goes above first line it truncates middle to fit first line and if text length goes to above second line then it truncates middle and show on two line.

My Code:

```
    self.testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.testLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.testLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
    self.testLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200;

    [self.testLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [self.testLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [self.testLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.testLabel];

    NSArray* constrs = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[_testLabel]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_testLabel)];
    [self.view addConstraints:constrs];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[_testLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_testLabel)]];
    [self.testLabel addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_testLabel(42@250)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_testLabel)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Folk there are lot of blogs that help in to configure your label according to your requirements.

[Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

The above link will surely help you. Indeed

Cheers!!!