# Set the Text in the UILablel both vertically and horizontally centered without changing the frame

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa, uilabel

As stated in the Title , I would like to center the Text in a UILabel both horizontally and vertically ..
I can vertically align it if i call `size to fit` and horizontally align it through `setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` 
But using both together seem to counteract one another ..

The green part is the UILabel and the red is the text ..

[image]

I would like to vertically align the text as seen in the image
Thanks !

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?rq=1

Comment: Did .. 
it dint seem to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try to implement this logic:


-(void)adjustLabel1Text1:(NSString *)text1 
{
    UILabel *lbl_first = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];



    text1 = [text1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


    float hedingLblHeight = [self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:text1 : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] :118 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    lbl_first.text=text1;


    [lbl_first setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_first.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y, 118, hedingLblHeight)];
    lbl_first.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lbl_first.numberOfLines = 0;
    [lbl_first sizeToFit];




//////////Adjust the lable or any UIControl below this label accordingly.

    float endResultHeight=[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:text2 : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] :299 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if(hedingLblHeight>secondImgTitleHeight)
    {
    [lbl_endResult setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_endResult.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y+lbl_first.frame.size.height+5, 299, endResultHeight)];
    }
    else
    {
        [lbl_endResult setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_endResult.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y+lbl_first.frame.size.height+5, 299, endResultHeight)];

    }

    lbl_endResult.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lbl_endResult.numberOfLines = 0;
    [lbl_endResult sizeToFit];



}

-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*)text : (UIFont*) withFont:(float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{

    CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

    return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

It has helped me a lot.Hope it works for you.