# How to align UILabel text from bottom?

Tags: iphone, ios, alignment, uilabel

How the `UILabel` can be aligned from bottom. Let say, my label can hold three line of text.If the input text is single line, then this line should come bottom of the label.Please refer the below image for better understanding. The orange area is the full frame of label.Currently it has one line and it is aligned center. So what I want is, it should always aligned bottom regardless of how many lines.

[image]

Please suggest your ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing that...

**1.** First set `numberOfLines` to 0 and then use `sizeToFit` property of `UILabel` so your `UILabel` display with its `contentSize`.

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

[yourLabel sizeToFit];
```

See more information from this link: [Vertically align text within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

**2.** Another option is to take `UITextField` instead of `UILabel` and set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` like below...

```
[yourTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

and then set the `contentVerticalAlignment` property to bottom like below...

```
[yourTextField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom];
```

**UPDATE**

Also, with `UITextField`, we can't achieve multiple lines. So instead we can use `UITextView` and set its `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`. Then, use the code below to make it bottom aligned.

```
CGFloat topCorrect = ([label bounds].size.height - [label contentSize].height);
topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
label.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
```

Comment: I have already tried first solution. But its not working properly.Its always aligned in the top and left. But it should be aligned at bottom and centre always. But second solution seems to be working. what about multiple line in second solution? will it be possible?

Comment: suppose this frame with 3 line is `CGRectMake(10,100,100,300);` then if you get one line only then set frame like that `CGRectMake(10,260,100,300);` , here just set some custom code with logic **otherwise** second option is best :)

Comment: Ya second is best.I will try and let u know.

Comment: I tried,it seems working.But the problem is, how to enable multi-line for UITextField?

Comment: Hi I implemented the same concept in UITextView. Its working perfectly. Thanks.. I have updated your answer which I implemented in my code.

Comment: Hi can u edit your answer, So it will be suits best for my question.Currently its incomplete.

Answer (score 27):

Swift 4.2 version using the `contentMode` property to set top and bottom:

```
class VerticalAlignedLabel: UILabel {
    
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        var newRect = rect
        switch contentMode {
        case .top:
            newRect.size.height = sizeThatFits(rect.size).height
        case .bottom:
            let height = sizeThatFits(rect.size).height
            newRect.origin.y += rect.size.height - height
            newRect.size.height = height
        default:
            ()
        }
        
        super.drawText(in: newRect)
    }
}
```

Then setup your label like that:

```
let label = VerticalAlignedLabel()
label.contentMode = .bottom
```

Comment: Worth noting that this works seamlessly with a custom-classed UILabel in IB (set contentMode there) and also that `sizeToFit()` is not required with this solution.

Comment: This answer is great 

Comment: how can you get interface builder to update the position of the displayed label? is that not possible?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet you can try to add (at)IBDesignable on the line before the class initialization. Replace (at) with @. More info here: https://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/#ibdesignable

Comment: hmm, yeah I had that but it wasn't working. Maybe I edited something important. I'll test it again monday

Answer (score 20):

Subclass UILabel

```
@interface Label : UILabel

@end
```

Then override drawTextInRect like so

```
@implementation Label

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(alignment == top) {

        rect.size.height = [self sizeThatFits:rect.size].height;
    }

    if(alignment == bottom) {

        CGFloat height = [self sizeThatFits:rect.size].height;

        rect.origin.y += rect.size.height - height;
        rect.size.height = height;
    }

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}

@end
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly for me, with almost no effort, and it doesn't feel hacky like some of the other solutions on here.

Answer (score 3):

i only set a bottom constraint to the super view in IB which works for me without using code and also number of Lines for a maximum constraint.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem and was able to solve it by putting my label in a stackview by itself. I got the idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737798/bottom-align-the-text-of-a-sequence-of-uilabels-within-a-horizontal-uistackview) which had the same question but with multiple labels. The same technique can be used with a single label.

The stackview would have axis = horizontal and alignment = bottom (which is what does the trick).

My label is now perfectly aligned towards the bottom which is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Put your UILabel in a vertical UIStackView with a dummy view as a spacer.
Also, set the dummy view with a lower hugging and compression priority.

Top to Bottom:

- Label
- Dummy View

Bottom to Top:

- Dummy View
- Label

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCe0X.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** version of @Dustin code:

**Subclass**:

```
class VerticallyAlignedUILabel: UILabel {
    
    enum Alignment {
        case top
        case bottom
    }
    
    var alignment: Alignment = .top
    
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        var rect = rect
        if alignment == .top {
            rect.size.height = sizeThatFits(rect.size).height
        } else if alignment == .bottom {
            let height = sizeThatFits(rect.size).height
            rect.origin.y += rect.size.height - height
            rect.size.height = height
        }
        super.drawText(in: rect)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let myLabel = VerticallyAlignedUILabel()
myLabel.text = "vertically aligned text"
myLabel.alignment = .bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is how I made to align the text to the bottom of my UILabel:

```
- (void)alignLabel:(UILabel *)l withText:(NSString *)text verticalAlignOption:(int)vertAlign{
CGSize stringSize = [text sizeWithFont:l.font constrainedToSize:l.frame.size lineBreakMode:l.lineBreakMode];

switch (vertAlign) {
    case 0: // align = top
        l.frame = CGRectMake(l.frame.origin.x,
                                   l.frame.origin.y,
                                   l.frame.size.width,
                                   stringSize.height
                                   );
        break;
    case 1: // align = bottom
        l.frame = CGRectMake(l.frame.origin.x,
                                   (l.frame.origin.y + l.frame.size.height) - stringSize.height,
                                   l.frame.size.width,
                                   stringSize.height
                                   );
        break;
    case 2: // align = middle
        // default
        break;
}

l.text = text;
}
```

Ahd you simple call the method like this to align to the bottom:

```
[self alignLabel:self.mediaTitle withText:@"My text to align" verticalAlignOption:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: use one label for your background color, I call this one originalLabel, and another for the text, called textLabel in my example. Then calculate the height and Y coordinate for textLabel:

```
[textLabel sizeToFit];
int height = textLabel.frame.size.height;
int yCoord = originalLabel.frame.origin.y + 
          originalLabel.frame.size.height - height;
textLabel.frame = CGRectMake( originalLabel.frame.origin.x, yCoord,
          textLabel.frame.size.width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

In IB as @Tobe said Bottom constraint to superview should work, 
Incase if you have multiple subview or horizontal stack view with one element to have bottom constraint then use Layout Margin to be Fixed with bottom less than other margins 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
class VerticalAlignedLabel: UILabel {
  
  let bottomSpacing: CGFloat = 10.0
  
  override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    var newRect = rect
    let height = sizeThatFits(rect.size).height
    
    newRect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - height - bottomSpacing
    newRect.size.height = height
    
    super.drawText(in: newRect)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can subclass `UILabel` and overriding the method :

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

call super `drawTextInRect` with the rect where you want to use.

Comment: You can also use - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines;
which may be more explicit.

Answer (score -2):

2021. use autoLayout)

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
textLabel.textAlignment = .center

textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: sView.topAnchor).isActive = true
textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```