# why is adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth not working?

Tags: iphone, ios

I　want to let label show itself and fit the string in it to the label width.in other words.  I use the property adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth to do so. But the string still show on the left of label.Why? Is there any other solutions to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel) answer to see if it helps.