# OHAttributedLabel shrink font size

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to get OHAttributedLabel to automatically scale down the font according to the defined width of my OHAttributedLabel frame. I am looking for a method similar to

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a detailed answer on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel), you just need to add it all in a method to get it done.