# How to adjust UIlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I read this answer in how to adjust the height of my label based on the text of the label: 
   [Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel/1054681#1054681)

This is my code trying to set new Text and adjust the label at the same time.

But what I find out is the height of the label never get changed. It ways stays at the value I set in my xib file. I use tool, Spark to inspect the height of the  label:

```
-(void) setNewText(NSString *)newText
{
     self.myLabel.text = newText;
     self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
     [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
     [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Updated:

I have tried @rdelmar suggestion. Set the width constraint for the label and num of line to 0. The height of the ui label does get adjusted. But there are extra spacing before and after the first/last line of the text.

[image]
Here is the screenshot I captured using Spark. The blue rectangle is the UILabel. As you can see, there are extra spacing before/after the first/last line. How can I remove those spacing?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout in your xib?  If so, you need to adjust the constant on the layout constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything in code to get your label to adjust its height. In the xib or storyboard, give the label constraints to set its position, and give it a fixed width constraint. Do not set its height. Set the numberOfLines to 0, and that's all you need to do. If you set the text with a string that's too long to fit on one line, the label will adjust its height automatically.

Comment: Thanks. But what width I should set the fixed width to? I want it to layout well in both iPhone 5/6 so the width of the label is different.

Comment: @n179911, you can set the width several ways. If you want it to adjust to screen width, then give it spacing constraints to the left and right edges of the superview instead of a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested: Have 1 width constrain for the UILabel. set the number of Lines to 0. That is.  The height of the Label does get adjust as you said. But there are extra spacing before/after the first and last line of the text. I have updated my question with the screenshot.

Comment: @n179911, I don't see that extra space when I do the same thing, so I'm not sure what's going on. I've never used Spark, are you sure it's showing the correct frame? Try giving your label a background color, and see if it still looks like it has that extra space at runtime.

Comment: I tried setting the background color of my label to green. I still see extra space before the first line.

Comment: @n179911, I can't duplicate your problem, so I don't know what else to say.

Comment: I only have 1 Label in my xib file. And other than the 1 width constraints that u suggested. I have 3 other constraints which set the horizontal and vertical spaces. that is.

Comment: @n179911, What  constraints do you have? You should only need one vertical and one horizontal.

Comment: Thanks. @rdelmar. I have 1 top vertical constraints. 1 leading horizontal constraints. 1 trailing horizontal constraints.

Comment: @n179911, that sounds right, so I don't know why you're getting different results from me. Perhaps it's something with the font. What font and language is your text (I can't tell from your image).