# Vertically align text within a UILabel (xcode)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uilabel

Long time reader, first time poster. I have searched all over for a solution but I am yet to find an answer that works.

Ok the problem: I have a UILabel which gets text dynamically assigned to it. If I resize the label to cover the entire view controller the text is stuck in the middle. I found a bunch of solutions which say to add the following code:

```
detailsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
detailsLabel.sizeToFit()
```

However this doesn't do anything.

Can someone have a look at my code and provide suggestions?

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbldetails: UILabel!


var selectedBeach : Beach?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    detailsLabel.text = selectedBeach?.greaterDetails
    lbldetails.text = (selectedBeach?.beachName ?? "") + " Details"

    detailsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [detailsLabel .sizeToFit()]

}

@IBAction func dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Comment: so i guess you are not using auto layout?

Comment: Hi Andre Slotta, thanks for your comment. The auto layout box is checked on the view controller.

Comment: ok, and you setup the label in storyboard? did you setup any constraints?

Comment: I just dragged-and-dropped the label to the storyboard (I have also linked the label to the code behind) and I have not setup any constraints. Cheers :)

Comment: ok :) and where do you want that label to be vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. do the following:

1. drag LEFT from the label to the view, release and choose **Leading Space to Container Margin**
2. drag RIGHT from the label to the view, release and choose **Trailing Space to Container Margin**
3. drag UPWARDS from the label to the view, release and choose **Top Space to Top Layout Guide**

after that go to the label's size inspector and make sure that the constraints all have a constant of *Standard*.

last but not least go to the label's attributes inspector and make sure that the *Lines* property is set to 0.

feel free to ask if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct code in Swift is

```
detailsLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Without the [ ]

And for the Objective-C it's

```
[detailsLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Hi Stefan Salatic, Thanks for the quick response, I have updated the code with your suggestion however I get the exact same result.

Comment: Hi, if you need more information you can check out this complete answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following things to enable `UILabel` that support multiline.

```
 lbldetails.numberOfLines = 0
 lbldetails.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = lbldetails.frame.size.width
```

**Here i am consider that your UILable support dynamic height as per its text just issue regarding not displaying multiline.**

Kindly give following constraints to `UILabel`.
[image]

Hope this help you.

Comment: @flexo, let me know if you still have problem.

Comment: Hi None! Thanks for the comment. I have added your solution above to the code however I still get the same results. e.g. small square with ... inside it.

Comment: @Flexo, have your label get different height? as per different text.. just i want to get that weather issue with setting constraints or not?