# Swift get Y coordinate of current element

Tags: swift, position, coordinates, popover

I got some UILabel which can be pressed to open a menu. When pressed, they call my function with the label itself as a parameter. I make a popover that behave correctly in phone view but I would like to position it when it is on ipad view.

My problem is that I can not get the exact position of the UILabel that was pressed.

I tried

```
myYCoordinates = label.bounds.origin.y
```

or

```
myYCoordinates = label.frame.origin.y
```

to

```
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, myYCoordinates, 1.0, 1.0)
```

But I cant get the good coordinate.

I don't know if it is because my label are in a tableview with 2 section or if there is a way at all.

Thank in advance for the help.

---

Here is my sceen (cropped du to development confidentiality)
[image]
Here is what append when I press my label
[image]
And here is what I would like ti to look like
[image]

---

I tried 
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = label.frame

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Özgür Erzil answer, I found out that I could simply use

```
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = label
optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(label.frame.width, label.frame.height / 2, 1.0, 1.0)
```

By setting the source view to my label and using the label width and height to position it.

Thank

Answer (score -1):

if you create your UILabel dynamically, try to set the position when you set it like: 
 CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
```

or if it is in storyBoard, you have to use constraint methods and use autolayout. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

Comment: My label are created in the storyboard, I do not make them dynamically. There position on screen will also vary depending on the option I show / hide on screen. They are in my second section of my tableview.

Comment: What you linked was to vertically center a text in a UILabel but what I want to center is a popover added to the view... I will add an image of what I want to do in some minutes.

Comment: I edited my post with image of what i'm trying to do

Comment: try this: popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = yourTextField.frame

Comment: It almost does what I want, except that it is not aligned vertically with the label.... (check the update to see the result)

Comment: it is because your textfield position is probably 0, add the textview superview position too in this case and be sure if textfield is the selected one

Comment: I'm a little nood in swift, hw can I use the superview with the sourceRect?

Comment: try to reach the selected view with a parameter sender.In this case it will be a label. You can get it optionMenu.popoverPresentationController. sourceRect = sender.frame

Comment: I forgot to set the sourceView to my label, it is more easy like that, I posted the answer to be clear or would you prefer to edit your answer so that I can give you the green check answer ?

Comment: great that you did it, happy coding!