# Swift : align UILabel text in the top rather in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, text-alignment

I want the `UILabel` to start from the top even if the text is short it seems that 
`NSTextAlignment` doesn't work

[image]

```
cell.textContent.text = comments[indexPath.row]
cell.textContent.textAlignment = 




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //post's section == 0

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postCell
        cell.usernameLabel.text = "Steve Paul Jobs"
         cell.time.text = "9:42 PM"
         cell.commentsLabelCount.text = "12 Comments"
         cell.textContent.text = "Return the number of rows in the sectioReturn the number of rows in the sectioReturn the number of rows in the sectioReturn the number of rows in the sectioReturn the number of rows in the sectioReturn the number of rows in the sectio"

        cell.layoutSubviews()

    }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentCell
        // Configure the cell...
      cell.layoutSubviews()

    cell.usernameLabel.text = "Steve Paul Jobs"
    cell.time.text = "9:42 PM"
    cell.textContent.text = comments[indexPath.row]
     cell.textContent.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left


        return cell



}


import UIKit

class commentCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textContent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    userImage.clipsToBounds = true

}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textContent.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: Probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel

Comment: I check that it was written 6 years ago ! Almost EVERYTHING Changed and new hack are created at least in the storyboard

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your custom UITableViewCell class add this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textContent.sizeToFit()
}
```

Here's a link to a sample project just incase you want to reference how the cell and table is set up:
https://mega.nz/#!ZoZCgTaA!7gvkRw4pwecMfDXrNW_7jR2dKe2UR9jPsq9tp_CRIcU

Comment: Awesome but it changed only after I tap the each cell

Comment: Hmmm. That's odd. It works for me without having to tap the cell. Would you mind posting the custom cell and the cellForRowAtIndexPath code?

Comment: Try adding "return cell" inside the if statement of the cellForRowAtIndexPath function right after cell.layoutSubviews(). Nothing seems to be interfering with the label not updating properly.

Comment: Sorry it is there but I forget to add the full code

Comment: As it turns out, you don't even need "cell.layoutSubviews()." I am unable to determine why this still won't work though. Make sure you override the layoutSubviews function in both custom cells.

Comment: I added a link to my sample project where I tested the code. I am afraid this is all the help I can provide without viewing the project.

Comment: as you can see in the code above both are "override"

Answer (score 53):

Using Auto Layout in Storyboard will be very simple:

[image]

and

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

This can easily be done with auto layout. Ensure your text label is in the correct view.

1. Ensure your text label's number of lines is set to 0

[image: number of lines is zero]

2. Select your text label and pin the top, left, and right constraints. Hit the 'Add 3 Constraints' button at the bottom.

[image]

3. Update your frames (to see the updated alignment in storyboard).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In your custom UITableViewCell class add this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded() //This is the solution for :changed only after I tap the each cell
    textContent.sizeToFit()
}
```