# Set max lines to 3 and adjust height according to label content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I've created a label in a tableViewCell which contain a string of text. The size of the string can vary however it should maximum be 3 lines. However i can't seem to do this? What is the easiest way to create such a functionality in this label so far i've just created this label in my tableViewCell Subclass.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dummyLabel: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom UITableViewCell class add this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    dummyLabel.sizeToFit()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    dummyLabel.numberOfLines = 3
}
```

Similar post here about label resize in UITableViewCell: [Swift : align UILabel text in the top rather in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778316/swift-align-uilabel-text-in-the-top-rather-in-the-middle)

Comment: Does this work for regular labels on a View Controller?