# iOS best way to center special characters vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uilabel, special-characters

So this is a pretty straight forward question.

How do I best accumulate for special characteres to be **vertically centered** inside a `UILabel`?

See example images:

Centered:

[image]

Not centered:

[image]

Comment: Text in `UILabel` is always vertical centred. In your image it is also centred but seams there is line height that is giving space from bottom. Good explanation on topic [Vertically align text within a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You may try use `UITextField` instead, also set `textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` and `textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;`