# Place Text in Top part of UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, text, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that covers most of the view. When I place text in the label, the text is center in the middle of the label. I have tried everything by playing around with the options in the attributes inspector, however the text wont start in the top area of the label, instead it appears in the middle of the label.

[image: This is what happens]

Is there any way to places the text in the top part of the label??

(If someones is wondering, yes I want the UILabel to cover most of the view because some texts are longer then others, and some are shorter, and I would prefer the text to be placed on the top part and not the middle of the UIlLabel.)

Comment: use TextView Instead of Label. it will solve your problem.

Comment: Constrain the top of the label to the top of the view but don't constrain the bottom - allow it to expand as required to accomodate the text

Comment: Paulw11's suggestion is the best solution as UITextView is slightly heavier than a plain label.

Comment: use Size to Fit method http://stackoverflow.com/a/1054681/3800154

Comment: If I use a TextView when a large text is displayed the textView turns scrollable and the text is displayed from a lower part instead of the top area. If I don't constraint the bottom of the UILabel and I place a new object under it I'll have a height is ambiguous warning and it might visually be different on all devices.

Comment: @MayankPatel I've seen that thread before however didn't really help me because its out dated and it isn't swift.

Answer (score 1):

`UILabel` has an intrinsicContentSize matching the text contents. If you don't constrain the height, then it will automatically adjust. So you don't need to make it cover the entire view.

Instead, tag it onto the top with a fixed distance. Specify the bottom distance with greater-than-or-equal. This way the label can grow until it reaches the lower limit and then the text will begin to be truncated.