# Swift - Changing the vertical alignment of title for Header section in a TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

I am using the following code to populate the headers of my function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    switch section {

    case 0: "SECTION 0"

    case 1: "SECTION 1"

    default: break

    }

    return nil
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
    var title = UILabel()
    title.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!
    title.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font=title.font
    header.textLabel?.textColor=title.textColor
    header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

Now, I would like to be able to change the vertical alignment of the title in the section, like in the following picture:

[Changing the vertical alignment of the title in the section of the TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMRtU.png)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to vertically align the text in a UILabel. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel) SO post goes into more detail.

But you can accomplish a similar affect by adding the label to a parent UIView, and constraining it to the bottom. Then you can return that view in the `viewForHeaderInSection` tableview Data-source method

```
let headerView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)))
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 30))
label.text = "Some Text"
headerView.addSubview(label)
return headerView
```

Comment: Perfect! I deleted that two functions that I was using, and now I am using just your code inside the function "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?", as you said. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Glad to help!

Comment: This is the best solution, Thank you. One question though, when I scroll on my tableView - the header section doesnt go with the table view, it stays static. do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a footer if you want to drop your label a little bit down.

Answer (score -1):

This code will vertical align the label, not sure its a great approach but sure works. you would rather create a view and use viewForHeaderSection.

```
guard let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
header.textLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
header.textLabel?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```