# How to adjust two column custom cells, text alignment for multi-line simultaneously in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Problem Statement 1:** Unable to align two custom cells text simultaneously for multiline, as shown below.
[image]

You can see here, for multi-line cell both the cell contents are not at same starting top line.

When there is no multiline content, then it is ok, as shown in below

[image]

You can see, how both the cell contents are aligned on same line properly.

**Problem Statement 2:** And there is one more problem, if cell is having large content, it won't increase it's height, instead of that it gets small font size as shown below

[image]
Below is my coding stuff, by this way I've managed for two custom cell with multiline.

```
func tableView(tableViewData: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = tableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as! StudentCell

        if indexPath.row < self.mMeaningArray.count
        {
            cell.lblMeaning1.text = self.mMeaningArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lblMeaning1.text = ""
        }
        if indexPath.row < self.hMeaningArray.count
        {
            cell.lblMeaning2.text = self.hMeaningArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lblMeaning2.text = ""
        }

        self.allowMultipleLines(cell)

        cell.lblMeaning1.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.lblMeaning2.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func allowMultipleLines(tableViewCell:UITableViewCell)
    {
        tableViewCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        tableViewCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        tableViewCell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    }
```

I know, it is adjusting its font size, as per contents, but I want that, it should be a fixed font-size with multi-line and simultaneously it should align text properly.

I've search on various sites, links & refer multiple questions of stack-overflow, but for this situation, didn't find any solution.

Comment: Hi, are you using auto layout

Comment: Yes, I'm using auto-layout

Comment: Ok just wait, i will post answer.

Answer (score 0):

solution using AutoLayout in StoryBoard.

1) Set no of lines to 0 and text alignment to Left.

## [image: Image 1]

2) Set height constraint.

[image: Image 2]

3) The height Constraint should be in Relation - Less Than or Equal

[image: Image 3]

4) Add sizetofit in inside of cellForItemAtIndexPath method

labelname.sizeToFit()

5) Thats it. Now you will get the result like this. For clarity, I set label backgroundcolor as blue.

[image: Image 4]

Comment: If it is not working, Then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel

Comment: Try above mentioned URL.