# How to align text inside textView vertically?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, swift3

I want to align vertically the text inside my UITextView (so it will be in the middle of it).
How can i achieve that? 
I looked up and could not find any answer that could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to be more specific do you want to do it from storyboard or from code and if you want from code what version of swift do you use?

Comment: I use Swift 3. It would be better if it was from storyboard but i couldn't see an option for that

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Link your **Text View** to your **View Controller** and name it as you want (let's say `textView`).

In `viewDidLayoutSubviews` function put this line:

```swift
textView.centerVertically()
```

Then under the last curly bracket of your class put this extension:

```swift
extension UITextView {
    func centerVertically() {
        let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
        let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
        contentOffset.y = -positiveTopOffset
    }   
}
```

To use this function in `Swift 2.0` just change `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` to `CGFloat.max`

Comment: I want to center it 'vertically' in the container not 'horizontally'

Comment: @Volkan what do you mean vertically?

Comment: lets say i have a text for 2 lines only and my textview has a height for 200. I want to center that text vertically

Comment: There is no alignment specifically for vertical orientation. However, there are a number of strategies you can deploy see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel

Comment: @Volkan I edited my answer, use this extension and you will be good to go! 
Remember to accept the answer if it works thanks.

Comment: this answer is good, just put that code in layoutsubviews of the superview or viewdidlayoutsubviews in the controller

Comment: But this answer doesn't support multiline well no?

Comment: @Happiehappie I updated my answer as stan said you have to put this code inside viewdidlayoutsubviews to perfectly work.

Comment: and also, if you set new value to the .text also need to call method

Comment: How do I use this in a separate class that creates a multiline UITextView?  I tried putting ````textView.centerVertically()```` in ````override func layoutSubviews()```` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Greg Hi, are you trying to use it inside a cell or controller? Do you get an error or you don't see any change after you run it? Finally either you using `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you have to call `super.layoutSubviews` or `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews` before you call the method.

Comment: @mike vorisis, no, unfortunately, same problem with or without ````super.layoutSubviews()````.  I can show you my code if you can tell me how to do so.

Comment: @Greg so I understand you tried to use it in a cell not a controller right? (I didnt try this in a cell try to use it inside draw)

Comment: @mike vorisis - forgive me, I'm new with Xcode and Swift and some of the terminology has me baffled. It is inside ````class CreateTables: UIView{ ... }```` created by a ViewController.

Comment: Ok try to put it inside the draw (with super)

Answer (score 4):

src: https://github.com/soonin/IOS-Swift-UITextViewAlignTextVertically/blob/master/IOS-Swift-UITextViewAlignTextVertically/Extentions.swift

```
extension UITextView {
    func centerVerticalText() {
        var topCorrect = (self.bounds.size.height - self.contentSize.height * self.zoomScale) / 2
        topCorrect = topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect
        self.contentInset.top = topCorrect
    }
 }
```

Edit: It's recommended to call it in `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: Thank you ! The accepted answer did not allow me to scroll the textView while yours did ( I just had to call it in layoutSubview and it was okay)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this using the storyboard, you could add a view inside of your textView. Then, set the constraints that you used for the textView to the new view. Finally, add the following constraints to your text view:

- (right and left) O and point to the new view
- using the alignment constraints, add a vertically constraint.

  [image]

Comment: You can't put an UIView inside of UITextView.

Comment: Ahh this is really smart. He's saying put a textview (vertically aligned) inside a "parent" view.

Comment: This totally worked for me and was very easy to do. UNDERRATED ANSWER. I was would recommend having the "parent" view being a horizontal stack view, then set the alignment to "centered" so that the text view's height automatically adjusts to always keep it centered.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct, just want to add solution for those updating the textView on real time/onEditing.

Use the above extension and add the delegate method as well.

`func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.centerVertically()
 }`

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5

Put the following extension below your last curly bracket in your ViewController:

```
// MARK: - UITextView extension
extension UITextView {

    func centerVerticalText() {
        self.textAlignment = .center
        let fitSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fitSize)
        let calculate = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let offset = max(1, calculate)
        contentOffset.y = -offset
    }
}
```

Call this function **after** you set the text.

```
yourTextView.centerVerticalText()
```

Comment: only this line worked for me
self.textAlignment = .center

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your extension or extending class of UITextView

```
public func centerVertically()
{
    let iFont = font == nil ? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize) : font!
    textContainerInset.top = (frame.height - iFont.lineHeight) / 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**textContainerInset** worked for me instead of contentOffset.

```
extension UITextView {
    func centerVertically() {
        let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
        let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
        textContainerInset.top = positiveTopOffset
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is used to center the text horizontal.