# align text in uilabel to top of label when using top bottom trailing and leading

Tags: ios, xcode

I have `UIView` which has a child `UILabel`. I have read the following SO post about aligning the text to the top of the view : [Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel). I see the approach discussed here in different methodologies, but I have a special case: I don't want the `UILabel` in my case to go past the bottom boundary of the `UIView`. This seems though to prevent the auto resizing of the `UILabel` since now it is pinned to all four directions (Trailing, Leading, Top, and Bottom). Is this impossible to achieve?

The solution presented in the above SO post suggested doing Trailing Leading and Top with the idea that it would resize the Vertical dimension based on the instrinsic size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All you need is a constraint for the bottom space to superview (the UIView in this case) to be greater than or equal to 0. Number of lines for the label is 0.**

---

[image]

[image]

---

---

**Using your question as text:**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         text.text = "I have UIView which has a child UILabel. I have read the following SO post about aligning the text to the top of
 the view : Vertically align text to top within a UILabel. I see the
 approach discussed here in different methodologies"
     }
```

**You get**:

> [image]
>
> **The text stops when the label hits the bottom of the UIView.**

Comment: I think, bottom space should be `>= 8`

Comment: @Krunal OP wants text to not go past the UIView, so there’s no reason for 8

Comment: Dear, your answer is correction, there is not need to see OP's requirement. General point of view, you set padding of 8 points from Top, Left (Leading) and Right (Trailing). So you set bottom padding to `>=0`, then your text may touch to bottom line of view. But if you set bottom padding to `>= 8`, your text will set 8 points of space with bottom line of view also.