# UILabel align to Top Left in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel, text-alignment, text-align

I am adding text into description area. I increased the height of the label as description data has more text and it looks good if text is more but if there is only one line of description the text showed in middle of the label and it looks weird.

I am using this label inside UITableViewCell.

I found this post [Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel)
but it is not able to solve my issue. Because I want to do this thing in Xamarin.ios not in xcode.

Can anyone help me out on how to make the label text align to top left ?

Comment: The already asked question's answer are for Xcode. I want to achieve the top left alignment of label in Xamarin.ios

Comment: it's the same answer regardless of language - call the SizeToFit() method

Comment: used sizeToFit() method. It didn't solved the issue that's why I posted my question.