# How do we put the text above? UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uilabel

**

### i doing news app. And news content I get appears in the middle of the uilabel but I want it at the top.

**

```
private let articleContentLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.backgroundColor = .cyan
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 50/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFCompactDisplay-Ultralight", size: 16)
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(articleContentLabel)   
}

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        articleContentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                           y: articleImageView.bottom + 40,
                                           width: view.width - 50,
                                           height: 330)
    }
```

**this is screenshot in myapp**
[image]

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel

Comment: I've reviewed it, it doesn't work.

Comment: But I'm able to get the result from one of the answers to the question mentioned above

Comment: if you look at my codes. You will see that I am doing the same. label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much preferred way of doing UI layout, instead of setting the `frame` property is by using Auto Layout. You should set your label's constraints, but without explicitly specifying its height, so that it could be automatically calculated to fit the number of lines needed. Implementation should look something like this.

```
 articleContentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 articleContentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: articleImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 articleContentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
 articleContentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
```